# Excel File created as read only

Tags: c#, excel, file, readonly

I have created an Excel Add-in using VSTO in C#. I want to create a new Excel file from a template located on a SharePoint site. A file picker dialog box is used so the user can chose which file to use as a template. Everything works fine exept the new workbook is created as read only. If I copy the template file on my computer, and use the same program to pick that file as a template, the new workbook is not created as read only.

The file on the sharePoint is not being open elseware when creathing the new file. Is there a way to specify the sharePoint library is a safe source? Or to set the newly created workbook readonly property to false?

{

```
string pathSP= @”\\Business.sharepoint.com@SSL\teams\group\NDC\”;

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathSP))
{
    Excel.Application excelObj = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    Office.FileDialog fileDialog = excelObj.FileDialog[Office.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker];
    fileDialog.InitialFileName = initialPath;
    fileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = false;
    fileDialog.InitialView = Office.MsoFileDialogView.msoFileDialogViewDetails;
    fileDialog.Title = "Create Excel file from template";
    fileDialog.Filters.Clear();
    fileDialog.Filters.Add("Excel template", "*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xltx; *.xltm; *.xlt", 1);
    string TemplatePath;

    if (fileDialog.Show() == -1)
    {
        templatePath = fileDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1);
        fileDialog = null; 
    }
    else
    {
        templatePath=""
        fileDialog = null;
    }


    if (templatePath != "")
    {
        Excel.Workbook ws= excelObj.Workbooks.Add(templatePath);
    }

}     
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("SharePoint site is not available", "Create Excel file from template", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the two ways you mentioned:

1. set the share point library as a safe source - this can be achieved by setting the excel setting: Options -> Trust Centre -> Trust Centre Settings -> Trusted Locations -> add the sharepont location
2. set the file access (readonly=false) at the end of your process

Actually as a general practice when dealing with template file (not limited to excel), the system should copy the template file to a local temp location (ideally the running user's TEMP folder), use it and then delete it afterwards. this way would avoid all kinds of problems such as file-lock-by-other-user/process problems.

Comment: I tried both approach. 1 adding the SharePoint location didn't work, file still open as readonly. 2. The readonly properties appears to be readonly (get, but no set). So I went for the 3rd option, copy the file in the TEMP directory before using the .add methode and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So I think your problem is the Workbooks.Add(). Check out what Microsoft says about it:

> [Workbooks.Add()] Determines how the new workbook is created. If this argument is a string specifying the name of an existing Microsoft Excel file, the new workbook is created with the specified file as a template.

I believe the workbook you're creating is a carbon copy of whatever the sharepoint server has, including permissions. The fact it works locally is another clue that sharepoint might be fiddling with permissions.

I suggest try saving a copy of the file locally. You can even use the `SaveFileDialog` object to give the user a GUI to save their new copy.

```
SaveFileDialog userSaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();  
userSaveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel 2007 and later | *.xlsx, Excel Macro Enabled Worksheet | *.xlsm, I'm guessing this is a 2007 template | *.xltx, Template Macro maybe | *.xltm, I almost definitely think this is a template file | *.xlt";  
userSaveFileDialog.Title = "Save an Excel File";  
userSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog();  
this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(@userSaveFileDialog.FileName);
```

Once you're done, you can programmatically open the newly saved workbook using `userSaveFileDialog.FileName` as your filepath.